# how to copy a file from public network into aws s3 using AWS lambda in nodejs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to copy a file from a public network, e.g:
http://myvideo.com/porn/tca-333.mp4
into my s3 bucket:
let's say:
s3://mypublicstorage.example.com/porn/tca-333.mp4
using AWS Lambda.

problem is, the video could be pretty big in size like 2 ~ 10 GB.
if I were to fetch it using request library like superagent, all of it, will probably be stored in RAM, hence it'll not be enough.

AWS Lambda itself has a limitation of only having 500ish MB disk iirc.
is it impossible to do this task by AWS Lambda after all?

my current code is more or less something like:

```
request.get(srcUrl).then(resp => S3.putObject({Body: resp.body, ...}))
```

any suggestion?

Comment: You should be able to do this in AWS Lambda by utilizing in-memory streams instead of writing a temporary file to disk. That actually looks like what your current code is doing. Have you tried running that code on Lambda to see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to do it in lambda with 512 MB of RAM, and I got this error.
Error: Maximum response size reached
at Error (native)
...
...
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7) code: 'ETOOLARGE', response: undefined }

Upon further reading, there seems to be a support to do that using { Writable } from 'stream' things.
and then using S3.multipartUpload instead of S3.putObjects.

Haven't really succeded at it tho.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of a job, it is not possible simply using Lambda. You can setup an Architecture as follows.

- AWS Lambda Function to push a Job to a Queue in Amazon SQS.
- Setup an EC2 instance(s) to execute to pull the job from the Queue and download the file and upload it to S3. (Optionally to stop the EC2 once the job is done)
- For low frequent workloads you can optionally Start the EC2 instance from Lambda and program to self shutdown after processing a job and finds the Queue is empty .

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried not to going that path, because EC2 cost you hourly. 
where this action mostly run within minutes.

Haven't really seen a process that will take longer than 5 minutes.
But I guess, by the time I'll need it, AWS might have a longer timeout limit.